# How can I start confluent platform as linux services

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I downloaded and tried both debian packages and tarball distributions of confluent platform. I didn't find any script I can run as a linux service.
How can I run all the tools included in this distribution as linux services ?

Thanks